# Why is Rails 4 rendering my view when I use redirect_to inside of a respond_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

So inside the respond_to block the conditional `if stockUpdated and stock != {}` fails as expected and the `else` block runs (I've tested this with byebug). So the server should redirect but instead it renders. Another odd thing, is that since its rendering the `flash.now[:alert] -'...'` should work but that also doesn't display in the view (take my word for it).

controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
        if stockUpdated and stock != {}
            format.js
            format.html { 
                redirect_to user_path(@user), 
                notice: "#{stock.symbol} has been added to your portfolio!"
            }
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "We could not add that stock to your portfolio."
            format.html{redirect_to user_path(@user)}
        end
    end
```

server:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2017-01-13 11:48:21 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Stock Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "assets" ON "stocks"."id" = "assets"."stock_id" WHERE "assets"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
Rendered stocks/_stock.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 92ms (Views: 81.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `user_path(@user)` is `/users/1` ? If yes, then your server log is showing that route (the redirected one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `and return` after your redirect:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if stockUpdated and stock != {}
    format.js
    format.html { 
      redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "#{stock.symbol} has been added to your portfolio!"
    }
  else
    format.html{
      redirect_to user_path(@user), flash: {alert: "We could not add that stock to your portfolio."} and return
    }
  end
end
```